# why is the fourier transform in python only working while taking the absolute value?

Tags: python, fft

I encourted a very strange thing in python again. I wanted to plot the Fourier Transform of a sinus signal; so I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#--------------------- test -----------------------------------
#x axis
x02 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001) # start, stop, step
y02 = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x02)

#plot sin in time domain
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x02, y02, color ='b')
plt.grid()
plt.title('Sinus in time domain')
plt.show()

# Fourier transform
yf02 = np.fft.fft(y02)
xf02 = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y02), 0.001)

# plot the Fourier transform
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xf02, yf02, color ='b')
plt.grid()
plt.title('Sinus in frequency domain')
plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

now if I plot the absolute values of my Fourier transform with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#--------------------- test -----------------------------------
#x axis
x02 = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001) # start, stop, step
y02 = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0 * np.pi * x02)

#plot sin in time domain
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x02, y02, color ='b')
plt.grid()
plt.title('Sinus in time domain')
plt.show()

# Fourier transform
yf02 = np.fft.fft(y02)
xf02 = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y02), 0.001)

# plot the Fourier transform
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xf02, abs(yf02), color ='b')
plt.grid()
plt.title('Sinus in frequency domain')
plt.show()
```

it works:

[image]

Could someone explain me why ? I'm very confused and don't understand how np.fft.fft works despite reading every tutorial.

Comment: Your code plots the sin in time domain and the fft. But the plots you show doesn't seem to correspond to your code. You have no plot in time domain, and it's unclear where does the second plot come from. What part of your code is plotting the absolute value?

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve], since your current example code is, as stated, not reproducible.

Comment: I changed it, now it should be clearer

Comment: `np.fft.fft(np.arange(20)-10).dtype` ⇒ `dtype('complex128')`

Comment: Ok but what is this ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to plot, as `y`, a complex number?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Echoing [lamdoug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76730780/2749397) "_I would suggest reading up on the theory of the algorithm you're using!_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fourier transform is a complex-valued function.
When you plot the complex output of `fft`, matplotlib will actually plot the real component only. So what you’re looking at there is the real component of the FFT of an odd function, which is zero (up to rounding errors, note the 1e-12 in the vertical axis).

You could instead plot the imaginary component, or you could plot the magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the amplitude of a discrete fourier transform, you need to take the absolute value - this isn't just Numpy's implementation. I would suggest reading up on the theory of the algorithm you're using!

Comment: Ok such as what for example; It's difficult to find sources with this information

Comment: @Apinorr Pretty much any introductory DSP textbook will cover this in great detail. There's also the [PySDR guide](https://pysdr.org/content/intro.html)

Comment: Oki thanks a lot, I'm very unfamiliar with this topic, I think this will help